# 401 retry mechanism using Combine Publishers

Tags: ios, swift, networking, mobile, combine

Fairly new to Combine.
A common scenario using access tokens and refresh token.

You get a 401 and you need to handle it (call some service to refresh the token) before retrying the initial call again

```
func dataLoader(backendURL: URL) -> AnyPublisher<Data, Error> {
    let request = URLRequest(url: backendURL)
    return dataPublisher(for: request)
        // We get here when a request fails
        .tryCatch { (error) -> AnyPublisher<(data: Data, response: URLResponse), URLError> in
          guard error.errorCode == 401 else {  // UPS - Unauthorized request
                throw error
            }

          // We need to refresh token and retry -> HOW?
          // And try again 
          // return dataPublisher(for: request) 
        }
        .tryMap { data, response -> Data in
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {

                throw CustomError.invalidServerResponse
            }
            return data
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

How would I go about wrapping this "token refresh service"?

Comment: Haven't tested it, but an idea would be to catch the error, refresh the token, and to retry it using `retry(..)`. This recreates a failed subscription (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/3204751-retry).

Comment: Indeed. That's the exact steps. However, implementation wise would the "refresh token" part be it's own separate publisher? and how would you link it in the above example for instance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code mentions a “token” but you don't explain what that is. Let's assume you have a token type:

```
struct Token: RawRepresentable {
    var rawValue: String
}
```

And let's say you have a function that gets a fresh token asynchronously, by returning a publisher of the fresh token:

```
func freshToken() -> AnyPublisher<Token, Error> {
    // Your code here, probably involving a URL request/response...
    fatalError()
}
```

And let's say you generate the URL request for the data by combining some URL with the token:

```
func backendRequest(with url: URL, token: Token) -> URLRequest {
    // Your code here, to somehow combine the url and the token into the real ...
    fatalError()
}
```

Now you want to retry the request, with a fresh token each time, if the response is a 404. You should probably limit the number of tries. So let's write the function to take a `triesLeft` count. If `triesLeft > 1` and the response is 404, it will ask for a fresh token and use that to call itself again (with `triesLeft` decremented).

The goal is made more complex because `URLSession.DataTaskPublisher` doesn't turn a 404 response into an error. It treats it as a normal output.

So we'll use a nested helper function to process the output of the `DataTaskPublisher`, so that we don't have so much code nested inside closures. The helper function, named `publisher(forDataTaskOutput:)`, decides what to do based on the response.

- If the response is an HTTP response with code 200, it just returns the data. Note that it has to return a publisher whose `Failure` is `Error`, so it uses a `Result.Pubilsher` and lets Swift deduce the `Failure` type.
- If the response is an HTTP response with code 404, and `triesLeft > 1`, it calls `freshToken` and uses `flatMap` to chain that into another call to the outer function.
- Otherwise, it produces a failure with error `CustomError.invalidServerResponse`.

```
func data(atBackendURL url: URL, token: Token, triesLeft: Int) -> AnyPublisher<Data, Error> {
    func publisher(forDataTaskOutput output: URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Output) -> AnyPublisher<Data, Error> {
        switch (output.response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode {
        case .some(200):
            return Result.success(output.data).publisher.eraseToAnyPublisher()
        case .some(404) where triesLeft > 1:
            return freshToken()
                .flatMap { data(atBackendURL: url, token: $0, triesLeft: triesLeft - 1) }
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        default:
            return Fail(error: CustomError.invalidServerResponse).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
    }

    let request = backendRequest(with: url, token: token)
    return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
        .mapError { $0 as Error }
        .flatMap(publisher(forDataTaskOutput:))
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Comment: Very nice solution! Thank you

Comment: the error code to check here is 401 not 404, and the request shouldn't be retried in case of 401 returned by the freshToken function

Comment: I have a similar problem but with a different approach. Would appreciate if you guys can share your insights on this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67076317/refresh-token-mechanism-with-combine-framework-ios